# Correctly representing a $2^n < n!$ statement

Tags: logic, proof-verification

$$2^n < n!$$ After an inductive proof I determined that $2^n < n!$ is valid only for values greater than or equal to $4$.

So. How do I represent this conclusion?

Is this correct?

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n \geq 4 \implies  2^n < n!$$

Comment: Why do you have to use symbols instead of words?

Comment: @lhf : may be he wants to write it mathematically...

Comment: You might want a bi-implication, since presumably during your calculations you verified that the inequality fails at $1$, $2$, and $3$.

Comment: This might help(Stirling's approximation) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is correct! But better write in this way 
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\left(n\geq 4\Rightarrow 2^n<n!\right)$$